# dynamically changing the APEX_ITEM. TEXT value in Oracle apex

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I have an application where I have created classic report. it has 4 columns.

```
SELECT KEY,  
  APEX_ITEM.TEXT(6,attribute3,10) attribute3,  
  APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(3,KEY) ||  
  APEX_ITEM.TEXT(4,attribute1, 10) attribute1,  
  APEX_ITEM.TEXT(5,attribute2, 10) attribute2    
FROM table1 ;
```

I want to dynamically change the value for attribute2 based on attribute1.

`attribute2 = attribute3*attribute1`, where attribute3 will be pre-fetched and attribute1 will be `entered by user`.

I want to calculate attribute3 on-fly(dynamically), based on changes in attribute1.

`Version: 4.2.1`

Comment: Could you be more specific about what atribute1, 2 and 3 are?

Comment: attribute1,2,3 are number type. where attribute data is already available. and I am entering attribute1 data in classic report text field. attribute3 is classic report text field, whose data will be calculated dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a (moderately complex) dynamic action as follows.

1. Action fires when the user changes any element with name "f06" (i.e. attribute3 which you have defined with p_idx=>6).

[image]

2. The action taken is to run some Javascript that finds the other 2 elements named "f04" and "f05" in the same row, get the value of the "f04" and "f06" elements, multiply them and store the result in the "f05" element.

[image]

Comment: I tried above method, but its not working and not calculating the value on change. 

Recreated the scenario in ORACLE APEX.


Workspace:`APEX_DC`
username: `test1`
pwd: `Abcd#456`
App#: `47573`

Comment: I have fixed your dynamic action.  Javascript is very case-sensitive, you had `apex.jquery` when it should be `apex.jQuery`.

Comment: Probably best you change your password now!

Comment: Wouldn't set ID's for each item uppon creation be more straigh forward?

Comment: @Typo, I did ponder that myself, but then when an item is changed, say #f06_3 you need to find the corresponding items #f04_3 and #f05_3. You can do that using `substr` to get the "3" and constructing the other 2 ids, but I'm not sure it's any simpler than finding the items by name within the same row.  @Neurotic should certainly consider adding ids to the items and whether it makes work easier.