# Changing fields on dynamic oracle apex report

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex-5.1

Nor newbie and nor advanced apex user here,
But,
 I'm very naive on major client side web languages, and now I need to face it. And soon.
I have an example [here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=149232:6) - user : *test* and password *test*.
I'm based on the very same jquery and javascript function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003828/dynamically-changing-the-apex-item-text-value-in-oracle-apex), answered by Mr. Tony Andrews.
 At my app example, when the *priority* field is changed it puts in the value of ***A* field**, when its not 0, nor null . Its simply multiply the result in that field.
I'm trying to put a change priority script from priority field when its change. For example: When would change the priority of *id=1*, to 1,  the priority from *id=2* must be changed to *3* - the original priority from *id=1*. 
I know it's a very basic algorithm, but I don't know how to do it just in time, on javascript or jQuery calls on apex. I'm been trying to more complex manipulations on report, but I need to understand the basics first.

For clarification my query report and javascript execution is:

```
select distinct
apex_item.checkbox2(10,r.ID) ID,
apex_item.text(11,r.ID) ID_2,
apex_item.text(20,r.PRIORIDADE) PRIORITY,
apex_item.text(30,1) a,
apex_item.SELECT_LIST_FROM_LOV(31,r.PRIORIDADE,'LISTAPRIORIDADES',NULL,'NO') PRIORITY_LOV, 
apex_item.text(40,null) b,


(select seq_id from apex_collections c  where collection_name = 'COLECAO'  AND c001 = r.id
)sequencial
from REPRIORIZA r



order by id;    
     //javascript execution, on dynamic action:

    var target = apex.jQuery(this.triggeringElement).closest('tr').find('input[name="f30"]')
    console.log(target)
    var source = apex.jQuery(this.triggeringElement).closest('tr').find('input[name="f20"]')
    console.log(source)
    var result = target.val() * source.val();
    target.val(result);
    console.log(target)

        var target2 = apex.jQuery(this.triggeringElement).closest('tr').find('input[name="f40"]')
        console.log(target)
        var source2 = apex.jQuery(this.triggeringElement).closest('tr').find('input[name="f11"]')
        console.log(source2)
        var result2 = source2.val();
        target2.val(result2);
```

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this, my suggestion is as follows:

1 - Use the attributes 'p_attributes' and 'p_item-id' in your select when do you write apex_item code, like this:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_item.htm#AEAPI211

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_item.htm#AEAPI206

```
apex_item.text(
    p_idx  => 20,
    p_value => 1,
    p_attributes  => 'data-id="' || CUSTOMER_ID || '"',
    p_item_id => 'priority' || CUSTOMER_ID) 
priority,
apex_item.text(
    p_idx => 30,
    p_value => 1,
    p_attributes  => 'data-id="' || CUSTOMER_ID || '"',
    p_item_id => 'a' || CUSTOMER_ID) 
a,
apex_item.SELECT_LIST_FROM_LOV(
    p_idx => 31,
    p_value  => 1,
    p_lov  => 'LISTAPRIORIDADES',
    p_attributes  => 'data-id="' || CUSTOMER_ID || '"',
    p_show_null => 'NO',
    p_item_id => 'lov' || CUSTOMER_ID)
PRIORITY_LOV
```

When you do this, you can access every item from the same line easily. These select is from a example table in my workspace, adapt these data to your table.

2 - Create a dynamic action to trigger when change the lov, this dynamic action should execute a javascript code.

[image]

3 - In your javascript code of this DA you can get every element of the line with this code:

```
var lineId = this.triggeringElement.getAttribute('data-id');
var lovItem = document.getElementById('lov' + lineId);
var aItem = document.getElementById('a' + lineId);
var priorityItem = document.getElementById('priority' + lineId);
```

[image]

Now you can do everything with lovItem, aItem and priorityItem fields.

4 - in your example page, the id column are sequential, so you can get the next line just incrementing the lineId variable like this:

```
var nextLineId = lineId + 1;
var nextLovItem = document.getElementById('lov' + nextLineId);
var nextAItem = document.getElementById('a' + nextLineId);
var nextPriorityItem = document.getElementById('priority' + nextLineId);
```

*If the values are not sequential, maybe you can create one more attribute in your apex_item on the "p_attributes" parameter using lead or lag function. https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions

Comment: Many thanks,
  I had a help from a colleague, that implement the priorities changes, on page 5, using the dom approach. Your contribution will be valuable for improvements, especially from lov field.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

For the case what I asked a possible answer is :

```
var target = apex.jQuery(this.triggeringElement).closest('tr').find('input[name="f30"]')
//console.log(target)
var source = apex.jQuery(this.triggeringElement).find('input[name="f20"]')

console.log(source)
console.log('valor default: '.concat(source.context.defaultValue))
//var lista  =  apex.jQuery(this.affectedElements[0].innerHTML).find('input[name="f20"]')
var lista  =  apex.jQuery(source.context.form).find('input[name="f20"]')
console.log('lista: '.concat(lista))
for (var x=0;x<lista.length;x++){
    if (source.context.value == lista[x].value && source.context.defaultValue != lista[x].defaultValue){
        console.log(source)
        lista[x].value = source.context.defaultValue
        lista[x].defaultValue = source.context.defaultValue
        source.context.defaultValue = source.context.value
        console.log(lista[x])
    }
}
var colecao = apex.jQuery().find('input[name="f20"]')

var result = target.val() * source.val();
```

This code will change the value between one existing in another row. Tks for previous contributions!

Comment: For some reason the code has become useless. Returns an error in the context of the selected item. I believe this was due to the new version of apex 18.

Comment: Apex 18 obfuscate some resources like context and context.form. The lista variable, for example, is set now to var lista = apex.jQuery(source.prevObject[0].form).find('select[name="f13"]') . Working on...