# Oracle apex and jQuery - changing values from a select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, dom-events, oracle-apex-5.1

On this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49845821/changing-fields-on-dynamic-oracle-apex-report) I finally succeed to change two values from the same column - priority. I tried to do it on select list - column priority lov - but with no conclusive success. Selects don't have "default values" properties like text fields, so I tried to get it from the source.context.index properties. [Here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=149232:5) the oracle apex app, user and password test.
I'm considering to use pure Javascript, to deal with it.

The Javascript is triggered after change the select list:

```
   var source = apex.jQuery(this.triggeringElement).find('select[name="f31"]')
   console.log(source)
   var lista  =  apex.jQuery(source.context.form).find('select[name="f31"]')  
   console.log(lista)
   console.log('source.context.selectedIndex inicial ' +source.context.index)
   var valor_default = lista[0].selectedIndex
   console.log(valor_default)
   var index_default = apex.jQuery(this.triggeringElement).closest('select[name="f31"]').find('option[selected]')[0].index
   console.log('indice default:' + index_default)

    for (var x=0;x<lista.length;x++){
        if (source.context.selectedIndex == lista[x].selectedIndex && source.context != lista[x]){
            console.log('selectedIndex ' + source.context.selectedIndex)
            console.log('source.context')
            console.log(source.context)
            console.log('lista[x]')
            console.log(lista[x])
            lista[x].selectedIndex = index_default
            index_default = source.context.selectedIndex
       //     lista[x].defaultValue = source.context.defaultValue
        //    source.context.defaultValue = source.context.value

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fellows,

A possible solution was found.

On form properties - footer text, an array is build to get the indexes of object f31 - select list:

```
<script >
var listaOriginal  = document.getElementsByName('f31')
var valordefault = []
for (item of listaOriginal) {

    valordefault.push(item.selectedIndex)

}
    console.log(valordefault)
</script>
```

on change from select list the array is used to compare with the changes:

```
   var source = apex.jQuery(this.triggeringElement).find('select[name="f31"]')
   var lista  =  apex.jQuery(source.context.form).find('select[name="f31"]')  
   var valueDefault = lista[0].selectedIndex
    var happyIndex = ''



   for (var happy=0;happy<lista.length; happy++){
       if (source.context === lista[happy]){
           happyIndex = happy
       }
   }

for (var x=0;x<lista.length;x++){
    if (source.context !== lista[x] && source.context.selectedIndex == lista[x].selectedIndex){       

        var my_table = {};
        my_table.source_context_selectedIndex =  source.context.selectedIndex
        my_table.lista_x_selectedIndex = lista[x].selectedIndex
        my_table.valueDefault =  valueDefault[x]
        console.table(tabela)


        lista[x].selectedIndex = valueDefault[happyIndex]
        valueDefault[happyIndex] = valueDefault[x]
        valueDefault[x]=lista[x].selectedIndex


    //    source.context.defaultValue = source.context.value

    }
    console.log(valueDefault)
}
```

Comment: For some reason the code has become useless. Returns an error in the context of the selected item. I believe this was due to the new version of apex 18.

Comment: Apex 18 obfuscate some resources like context and context.form. The lista variable, for example, is set now to var lista  =  apex.jQuery(source.prevObject[0].form).find('select[name="f13"]') . Working on...